# Update Password option not updating in DB

Tags: php

Trying to set up a update password feature once you log in and go to profile page and I've been playing around with it but nothing works, I there aren't any errors but it doesn't update database.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$newpassword = $_POST['password'];
if(empty($newpassword)) {
    echo '<p>Field Empty!</p>';
} else {
$mysqli->query("UPDATE password FROM users WHERE password='$newpassword'");
echo "Updated Successfully"
}
}

 ?>
```

Comment: You don't want to run that query. (almost?) Always have a where clause on an update. This query as is will update all users passwords to the submitted password. Why do you need `SELECT password FROM users`?

Comment: This should not be work because to update a field you need a id field or other unique fields

Comment: Look at the update syntax, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html. `UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = 'VALUE' WHERE COLUMN ='VALUE'`. Notice the `where` clause that is important, that is how many rows will be updated. In your case I'd think `where userid = ?` assuming `userid` is unique. You also should not store passwords in plain text.

Comment: "once you log in and go to profile page" - how do you identify the user per request? Via _SESSION? Do you store e.g. the `id` that corresponds with the `id` field of the user record in the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell your query is wrong.

You need to add the ID of the row that you want to update. Which you should store in the session.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$newpassword = $_POST['password'];
if(empty($newpassword)) {
    echo '<p>Field Empty!</p>';
} else {
$mysqli->query("UPDATE Users SET password='$newpassword' WHERE ID=?");
echo "Updated Successfully"; 
}
}

 ?>
```

Changes I would make, you had some missing semicolon and you need to check the password on original post. Much cleaner to read.

```
  <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
        $newpassword = $_POST['password'];

        $mysqli->query("UPDATE Users SET password='$newpassword' WHERE ID=?");
        echo "Updated Successfully";

    }
    else {
        echo '<p>The password field is not filled in.</p>';
    }
   ?>
```

I hate insecure pages. Here is a much more secure way of doing this. It may have errors i did not test.

```
<?php


        // configuration
        $dbhost     = "localhost";
        $dbname     = "test";
        $dbuser     = "root";
        $dbpass     = "admin";

        // database connection
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST['password'])){



        // new data
        $UserID = $_SESSION['UserID'];
        $Password = $_POST['password'];

        // query
        $sql = "UPDATE Users SET password=? WHERE ID=?";

        $q = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $q->bindParam(1, $UserID);
        $q->bindParam(2, $Password);
        $q->execute(array($title,$author,$id));
    }
    else {
        echo '<p>The password field is not filled in.</p>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: thank you that worked! I had Id in there before but i guess i made a mistake someone so i took it out trying something else, thanks a bunch!

Comment: Just an FYI this is extremely insecure. Someone could delete your entire database if the wanted. You need to read up on prepared statements.